# List custom taxonomy specific to one custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, customization, loop

I am slowly going mad trying to figure this out..

I want to list custom post type 'mobile_review' by custom taxonomy 'mobile_phone', as multipe custom post types share this taxonomy I need some way to segment.

So far I have this:

```
function get_terms_by_post_type($taxonomies,$args){

 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'mobile_review'
);

// The query for posts of type 'mobile_review'
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

//get terms    
    //$mobs = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID,"mobile_phone"); 
     $mobs = get_terms('mobile_phone');
 $count = count($terms);
 if ( $count > 0 ){
 echo "<ul>";
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";

 }
 echo "</ul>";
 }

endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();        

}
```

Am I close? I have been hacking back and forth for ages and getting nowhere.

Any help would be great!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that will list all the `mobile_review` posts that have the term `htc_desire_hd` in the taxonomy `mobile_phone` :

```
$tax_query = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );

$tax_query[] = array( 
    'taxonomy' => 'mobile_phone', 
    'terms' => array('htc_desire_hd'),
    'field' => 'slug' 
);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'mobile_review',
    'tax_query' => $tax_query
);

$custom_loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 

if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) :

    while( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post(); 

            the_title();

    endwhile;

else :

    _e('Sorry, nothing here.');

endif;

wp_reset_query();
```

Now you can have the phones reviews by phone model, you just need to change the phone names, pass the name from a form, URL, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'mobile_review',
    'taxonomy' => 'mobile_phone'
);
```

Is that what you're looking for?